# How to collect all the print content and save them in a txt in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sys

I want to collect all of the print content and save them in a txt file. I use [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35779140/10844937) method to generate and collect logs. Also I use a `threading`, because in my real environment, `get_logs` and `make_logs` are in different thread.

```
import sys
import io
import time
import threading
import traceback

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, func, args):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.args = args

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.result = self.func(*self.args)
        except Exception as e:
            f = traceback.format_exc()
            print(f'{f}')
            
    def get_result(self):
        try:
            return self.result
        except Exception:
            return None

def make_logs(delay):
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
        print("\n")
        time.sleep(delay)


def get_logs(t1):
    if t1.is_alive():
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
        whatWasPrinted = buffer.getvalue()
        with open("output.txt", "w") as text_file:
            text_file.write(whatWasPrinted)
        time.sleep(1)
        get_logs(t1)
    

def do_it():
    t1 = MyThread(make_logs, args=(1,))
    t2 = MyThread(get_logs, args=(t1,))
    t1.start(), t2.start()
    t1.join(), t2.join()


old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = buffer = io.StringIO()
do_it()
```

However, as I execute this code, I can only write the first elment(0) to txt file. Anyone knows why? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "print context"? Do you mean the actual output rather than "context"?

Comment: python comes with a very handy logging module. check it out here https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

Comment: @JacoSolari That's not what OP is asking though.

Comment: @AKX that's why a posted a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: @tripleee all the print in my code.  Should be print content.

Comment: Do you want to redirect all the output to a file or just the output of a specific thread? I do not see the need for two threads here. Moreover, the easiest way would be to use the `file` argument to `print`

Comment: 1)The reason I use thread is because I need it in my real work. 2)I need the output of a specific thread. 3) can you write as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can set sys.stdout to a file object to redirect the outpus:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(PATH_TO_LOG_FILE, "w")
print('test')
do_it()
sys.stdout.close()
```

you can also use `contextlib.redirect_stdout`: (works for python 3.4+)

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open('help.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        print('it now prints to `help.text`')
```

Comment: Preferably use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) instead.

Comment: Hi, have you tried the second method, use `contextlib.redirect_stdout`, nothing new write in the txt file.

Comment: My python version is python3.9

Comment: try use the first method @jasonshu

Comment: @TalFolkman Can you add more details to the first method. A little confused.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two threads to capture the first N seconds – you can write a filelike object that stops writing to whatever backing object (here it just derives from `io.StringIO` but could wrap another IO) when it has had enough.

```
import contextlib
import io
import threading
import time


def make_logs(n, delay):
    for i in range(n):
        print(i)
        print("\n")
        time.sleep(delay)


class StdoutCapturer(io.StringIO):
    def __init__(self, time_limit):
        super().__init__()
        self.time_limit = time_limit
        # This could be initialized later, at the first write:
        self.start_time = time.time()

    def write(self, s: str) -> int:
        elapsed = time.time() - self.start_time
        if elapsed < self.time_limit:
            return super().write(s)
        return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sio = StdoutCapturer(time_limit=3.1)
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(sio):
        t = threading.Thread(target=make_logs, args=(5, 1))
        t.start()
        t.join()
    print(repr(sio.getvalue()))
```

This prints out

```
'0\n\n\n1\n\n\n2\n\n\n3\n\n\n'
```

### EDIT

Based on the comments, I think it wasn't clear what I meant with wrapping another IO, so here's a variant that writes the first N seconds to a file...

```
class TimeLimitedFileWrapper(io.TextIOWrapper):

    def __init__(self, raw_file, *, time_limit):
        super().__init__(raw_file, encoding="utf-8")
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.time_limit = time_limit

    def write(self, s: str) -> int:
        elapsed = time.time() - self.start_time
        if elapsed < self.time_limit:
            return super().write(s)
        return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("foo.txt", "wb") as f:
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(TimeLimitedFileWrapper(raw_file=f, time_limit=3.1)):
            t = threading.Thread(target=make_logs, args=(5, 1))
            t.start()
            t.join()

    with open("foo.txt", "rb") as f:
        print(repr(f.read()))
```

The output is the same.

Comment: Hi, where do you write the print content into the txt?

Comment: You could do `with open("something.txt", "w") as f: f.write(sio.getvalue())` at the end – or like my post says, you could instead directly write to the file in your wrapper object.

Comment: Thanks, maybe you ignore what I have write in my question"I may have to collect the first 5 seconds' logs for instance." To be more clear, we need 100 seconds to run  `make_logs`, I may have to fetch the first 5 seconds print content form the txt. However, in your method, the txt is generated when `make_logs` finished.

Comment: Yes - this example script runs `make_logs` for 5 seconds, and it logs only the first 3.1 seconds. And _again_, as the prose in my answer says, you could just as well wrap another file object instead of using `StringIO` for buffering.

Comment: @jasonshu Please see my edit.

Comment: Hi, I have tried using a file object to replace StringIO, and it not works. Can you share with me the wat you wrap file object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241000/discussion-between-jasonshu-and-akx).