# Is there a Python function equivalent to the ob_start() and ob_get_clean() in PHP?

Tags: python, php, function

I have this code:

```
line = input("Line of code: ")
output = exec(line)
```

Naturally it doesn't work because if you write `print("Hello World")` it only prints "Hello World" and the `output` variable will have None value.
So, in PHP I could use the output buffering in this way:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "Hello World";
output = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

Is there an equivalent function or a similar way in Python? This is exactly what I need.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What you are describing does not make much sense to do in Python as it does in PHP. It would be better to describe *why* you came to the conclusion that you need such a function. What else have you tried that did not work, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: further explain your end goal. I do not know PHP, but I can give the python version if I understand what you are looking for...

Comment: What is the intended value for `output`?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779023/get-text-contents-of-what-has-been-printed-python

Comment: @EliHarold I need to save the result of a `print()` in a variable.
In PHP there's a thing called Output Buffering that saves the result of a block of code in a variable.

Comment: I see, that does not make much sense in python. Why not save the values before you print them?

Comment: But @sudden_appearance seems to have linked your answer.

Comment: There are two different concepts going on here, and I think it's making the question more confusing. The PHP snippet doesn't reflect the fact that you're trying to [`eval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)uate arbitrary code. Ultimately (I think) what you're looking to do is read a line of code from user input, and then capture the **result** of that code.

Comment: @SimCop07 if what iainn said is true then `eval()` is a function that can "run" code from a string.

Comment: No, because if I want to run `var = value` I can only use `exec()`

Answer (score 0):

You could patch `print` to write into a [temporary buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html):

```
from io import StringIO

#line = input("Line of code: ")
line = 'print("Hello World")'


# patch print. All following print statements are writing into in-memory text buffer!
out = StringIO('')

# Keep reference to old print function
_print = print

# overwrite print, in order to write into StringIO
print = lambda x: _print(x, file=out)
print("Before.")
exec(line)
print("After.")
print = _print # Switch back to original version
print(out.getvalue())
```

Out:

```
Before.
Hello World
After.
```